# How can i get custom fields on ModelSerializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-serializer

I have a model

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    status = models.OneToOneField(Dictionary, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    money = models.IntegerField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
```

My urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('get', views.GetViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})),
]
```

My view

```
class GetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        GeneralSerializer.Meta.model = Teacher
        return GeneralSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        return self.select_api()

    def select_api(self):
        queryset = Teacher.objects.values("name","money").annotate(Count("money"))
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

serializer

```
class GeneralSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = None
        depth = 2
        fields = '__all__'
```

in this example in annotate func i have  +1 field "money__count" but i can't display it cause my model have not a this field. How can i display it in api and i want a universal serializer (without adding static field to serializer cause it is universal serializer for all models)

Please help me

Comment: Try using https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

Comment: It is not for me. Because i have universal serializer for all models. and i need dynamic add field to serializer(not static field in serializer)

Comment: Why would you want that? This is very weird usage of Serializers